# How does pornhub infer gender?

Tags: privacy, internet

The adult website Pornhub (very NSFW) has an active [data science blog](http://www.pornhub.com/insights/) (mostly SFW) that tracks usage statistics.

One frequently reported statistic is gender, as exemplified by the SFW post ["Women and Tech"](http://www.pornhub.com/insights/women-and-tech) where age, OS, browser, location, access device, and gender are all reported on. While some of these variables can be inferred from IP and user-agent, I can't figure out how they determine gender or age. If this information is leaking from an ad network, how can I as a user see what is known about me?

Comment: Isn't this a question for their data science team? We can only guess. If you question is how *anyone* could determine gender, then maybe that's a question, but I'm not sure it's a security question.

Comment: Here's a question: are these women registered users of the site where they have specified their gender?

Comment: Tracking cookies.

Comment: @schroeder 1] Looking at the numbers of registered users vs the stats they displayed, I don't think the data is coming from that. 2] Should the question be reworded to make it generic to any website, or should I post a new question? I _think_ generically this is  valid on-topic infosec question, but I may have been too specific -- any mod advice?

Comment: There are just too many ways to infer things like this. We can only guess

Answer (score 0):

I would go there and look right now but my Wife is right next to me so its probably a bad idea. A good place to find information about this is here: https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/ads/

Different sites use certain cookies that basically profile you and store that information remotely.  When you go to another site that is using the same services, they can request an ad, and something relevant to your past browsing history or location will be served up.

This is usually done by the use of cookies.  For example, google uses the id or IDE cookie stored in browsers under the domain doubleclick.net. Any site can use google's api to serve you content that is relevant to you.  There are many more sites and cookies that do the same.